# What happens if a process preempts while executing wait and signal operations?

Tags: operating-system, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

The main reason for using semaphores is to prevent the producer-consumer problem.
But I wonder what would happen if a process gets preempted while executing wait operation and another process also executes wait operation.

Let's take 
S value as 1.
What if while executing **Wait()**, S value is loaded into register **reg** as 1.
now S value is decremented.
Now reg is 0.
And now if another process wants to execute the wait to access the critical section
it considers S value as 1.
loads reg as 1.
and again decrements.
reg is 0.

Now both processes enter the critical section.

The code for the wait function is

```
Down(Semaphore S){
S.value=S.value-1;
if(S.value<0)
{
put PCB in suspended list;
sleep;
}
else
return;
}
```

The code for the signal function is

```
Signal(Semaphore S){
S.value=S.value+1;
if(S.value<=0)
{
Select a process from suspendend list;
wakeup();
}
}
```

isn't semaphore variable also a critical section variable as it is common for two or many processes? how can we prevent such race conditions?

Comment: That cannot happen with a semaphore, by definition.  If it can happen, as with your example code, it is not a semaphore.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that if the code for semaphore operations is as given above, there is indeed a risk that something bad could happen if a thread gets preempted in the middle of implementing an operation. The reason that this isn’t a problem in practice is that the actual implementations of semaphore operations are a bit more involved than what you gave.

Some implementations of semaphores, for example, will begin by physically disabling the interrupt mechanism on the machine to ensure that the current thread cannot possibly be preempted during execution of the operation. Others are layered on top of other synchronization primitives that use similar techniques to prevent preemption. Others might use other mechanisms besides disabling interrupts that have the same effect of ensuring that the process can’t be halted midway in the middle of performing the needed synchronization, or at least, ensuring that any places where preemption can occur are well-marked and properly thought through.

Hope this helps!